# VSCode Maven CommandNotFoundException after setting the environment variables

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code, javafx, installation

I tried setting up Maven for VSCode. I could start a maven javafx project and now it gives me this error from the pom.xml file:

org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:win:13 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:win:13 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled.

I tried this solution which I couldn't execute:

```
Step 1: Right Click on your project: Run (As) -> Maven clean
Step 2: Right Click on your project: Run (As) -> Maven install
After which, if the build fails when you do Maven Install, it means there is no web.xml file `under WEB-INF or some problem associated with it.`
```

When I right click in VSCode on the maven project and click on clean it gives me the error CommandNotFoundException

> & : Die Benennung "C:\Java\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.5" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren
> Programms erkannt. Überprüfen Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten), und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
> In Zeile:1 Zeichen:3
>
> - & "C:\Java\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.5" clean -f
>   "c:\Users\ahmet\OneDriv ...
> - ```
>   + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Java\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.5:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```

A tutorial showed me how to set the home variables for maven. I set it like advised:

1. M2_HOME to C:\Java\Maven\apache-maven-3.8.5
2. MAVEN_BIN to %MAVEN_HOME%\bin
3. MAVEN_HOME to %M2_HOME%

Afterwards I was able to call mvn -v in cmd and also in VSCode but I still couldn't clean the Maven project. So I [this](https://dzone.com/articles/how-resolve-mavens-failure) solution removing the old dependencies which worked in the VSCode command line. It worked but when now calling the clean command it gives me a commandNotFoundExceptopn. So I was wondering how to setup maven properly.
The project is located in a OneDrive directory ready on the local disk.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zt3MS.png)

Comment: This: `The operation was cancelled.` looks weird..network/internet issue ? Also check the build on plain command line outside of your IDE...

Comment: I'm in a hospital right now using the clicics wifi. It works now after clicking on update project in vscode explorer, It still gives the error CommandNotFoundException when executing any maven command.

Edit: Now it worked! I had to remove the maven path in VSCode which lead to a conflict in the path to maven.